# Connection lost using Twisted FTPClient storeFile

Tags: python, ftp, client, twisted

I am attempting to use Twisted to run an FTP client/server on my computer.  I can successfully connect and do things like list the files in the directory of a given user, and retrieve files, but when I attempt to use the `storefile` function of `FTPClient`, I only get a connection lost error.  Here is my code for sending the file.

```
spath = 'client_text.txt'
fileObject = open(spath, 'r')
ft = FileSender()
d1, d2 = ftpClient.storeFile(spath)
d1.addCallbacks(sendFile, sendFileFail)
d2.addCallbacks(success, fail)
```

and I get the error

```
[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.protocols.ftp.ConnectionLost'>: ('FTP connection lost', <twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>)
```

Any help with Twisted FTP would be nice, including any link to a fully functional example of the STOR command using Twisted.